# Bluetooth Low Energy on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-7, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here's the problem - I need my Bluetooth Low Energy-Only device to be able to connect to Windows 7 computers. Preferably using a regular CSR dongle, if possible. Is there any way or workaround?

Comment: Why shouldn't this be possible? I'm working with BLE and Windows 7 all the time, although using a PTS dongle. But CSR dongles also work fine.

Comment: @Nebr Windows 7 doesn't support BLE, can you link me to the API that you are using?

Comment: I have to correct myself a bit: There is no open source or standard BLE stack for Windows 7. You will need a proprietary stack. I am using this here: http://www.stollmann.de/en/software/bluetooth-bluetooth-low-energy/bluecode-protocol-stack.html. So it is in fact possible, but probably you are looking for free software, which does not exist (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: @Nebr Thank you! I am not necessarily looking for free software, your link is great.

Comment: @Nebr I'll send them an email, but do you know what programming languages their APIs are in, and also if you can tell me, how much it might cost? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, it is C/C++, but wrappers for other languages exist. (I use a wrapper for C#.) Unfortunately, I don't know the costs.

Answer (score 4):

I spent the two last days googling stuff to make my designer mouse working on my Lenovo T450 under Windows 7.

The solution I found may not apply to everyone: your computer must have a Bluetooth 4.0 capability (which as I understand allows Bluetooth Low Energy (aka BLE or Bluetooth Smart) to work.

The BLE drivers are not native to Windows 7 so you need to install them: go to your manufacturer's website and download the latest **Intel Bluetooth drivers**. Depending on the make, they might have various combinations of drivers (sometimes with overall wireless drivers, sometimes Bluetooth separately,.. I had to try about 3 - 4 different without really knowing what they meant). Once those drivers installed, you should be able to see your mouse/keyboard and pair to them. 
I had to reboot my laptop multiple times and had to download a lot of different drivers from various sources but the one thing that worked was googling: **Intel Bluetooth driver "your laptop make and model"** and downloading the drivers.

Ps. I have also downloaded the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" application and although opening it and trying to use it did not help at all, it might have help setting something in the background that made the drivers get installed smoothly (not an IT person, I have no idea).

I hope it helps!
Good luck

Comment: How would that work? What API would you use the make the connection and transport data?

Comment: Thank you very much for this input. Worked for connecting BLE mouse to HP ProBook 450 with Intel WiFi/Bluetooth card on Windows 7 - the first driver shot according to specification at the underside of a laptop :).

Answer (score 1):

You need Bluetooth hardware that supports Bluetooth 4.0 or higher. Then just install the driver for Windows 7. Don't use Windows' internal update service (its lying and will tell you that your driver is up to date). I used this:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28510/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-for-Windows-7-

Answer (score 0):

Well, Logitech Mx Anywhere 2 surprisingly started working with Windows 7 (Dell 380 Module on E6430 laptop) with IVT Bluesoleil Stack (unfortunately not freeware). Context menu of its icon in tray has "Bluetooth 4.0 functions", that allow adding BLE/Smart devices.